# Count the occurrence of consecutive 1s in 0-1 array

Tags: java

I have a set of 1s and 0s. How do I count the maximum number of consecutive 1s?

(For example, x = [ 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 ]). Here the answer is 3 because the maximum number of times 1 occurs consecutively is 3.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Grab a pencil and a piece of paper and start counting and annotating the result of your count in the paper with the help of the pencil.

Comment: Do you know how to use `if` and loops (`while` and `for`)?

Comment: No need to abuse new users. Just explain what this is all about here (http://stackoverflow.com/help) and let them fix their question properly.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the array, keeping the count of how many consecutive 1s you've seen. Whenever you see a 1, increment the count. Whenever you see a 0, reset the count to zero. The answer to your problem is the largest counter value seen during the iteration.

Comment: Whenever you see a 0, reset the count to zero." if i have "11101", cpt=1 !!

Comment: You have another integer that tracks the max count of 1s seen so far.
ex. 11101
At the end of your iteration you have something like:
currMaxCount = 3
currCount = 1

Answer (score 1):

```
int cnt = 0,max=0;
for(int i=0;i<x.length;i++){
   cnt=0;
   while(i<x.length&&x[i]==1){
      cnt++;
      i++;
   }
   if(cnt>max) max=cnt;
}
```

this should work

Comment: ... next time, don't give the code away....

Answer (score 1):

Since this smells like homework, all you get is an algorithm!

Initialize counter, max 
For all the elements in the Array.
If element is '1'
increment the counter 
Else 
max=GetMaxOf(max, counter)
reset counter
End If
End For

Comment: you should only set the max if it is bigger than the current max.. could be something like: max = Max(max, counter)

Comment: @sarseyn, true, missed that. Thanks for pointing it out.